# Reload page on scss save

Tags: angular, gulp, gulp-livereload

I am playing with Angular 2 using official [Quick start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#) guide.

Dev Dependencies from the package.json file allow live reload by saving html files.

I also use Gulp and live reload scss to css for decorating my stuff.

What I want is to bind Gulp's scss live reload with Angular 2's html live reload. I mean when I save changes either in a scss or in an html file, I want these changes to be done with the live reload.

For now I can make scss and html changes only separately by running either a Gulp command or the npm start command in Terminal.

My gulpfile.js code:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
      return gulp.src('app/assets/scss/styles.scss')
   .pipe(sass())
   .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
});
```

My package.json code:

```
{
 "name": "app",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
 },
 "license": "ISC",
 "dependencies": {
   "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
   "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
   "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
   "core-js": "^2.4.1",
   "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
   "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
   "systemjs": "0.19.27",
   "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
   "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
   "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "browser-sync": "^2.16.0",
   "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
   "gulp": "^3.9.1",
   "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
   "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
   "typescript": "^2.0.2",
   "typings": "^1.3.2"
 }
}
```

Comment: This tutorial explains how to compile scss to css and even do live reload: https://medium.com/@lampt2509/set-up-persistence-scss-from-chrome-devtools-for-angular-220ce0818568

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to tell your gulp to watch for changes in your `scss` file.

In you **gulpfile.js**

```
//Watch task
gulp.task('sassWatch',function() {
    gulp.watch('app/assets/scss/**/*.scss',['sass']);
});
```

Second, you have to start this gulp watch concurrenctly to tsc watch and the lite server.

In your **package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run sass:w\" \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",

    "postinstall": "typings install",

    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",

    "sass": "gulp sass",
    "sass:w": "gulp sassWatch", 

    "typings": "typings"
 },
```

Comment: Yes, but actually it doesn't change anything. It allows to make changes of scss file using Gulp or html (ts / js...) using npm start command in Terminal

Comment: Maybe lite-server does not look for change in css files by default. Did you try to customize the lite-server configuration ?